# Watir: Can I tunnel through an *External* HTTP/SOCKS proxy over Firefox?

Tags: watir

I would like to know if I can invoke watir and have it tunnel through a proxy. And If i can change this proxy at runtime and also if I can set the proxy for each instance (when runnnig multiple instances/tests). I pretty much intend to use firefox.

Answer (score 1):

If you were thinking about running multiple instances you could try the watirgrid gem (I'm the author of that one, disclaimer :-)

In terms of running through a proxy, and because you're using firefox, then you could try something with watir-webdriver with the [selenium server jar](http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.0b1.jar)

So start your selenium server:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0b1.jar
```

Your code would look like this:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => :firefox)
```

where 127.0.0.1:4444 (the selenium server) could possibly be changed via a reverse-proxy ... I haven't really tried it. You wouldn't really need to anyway.

You could just have N remote servers and call each of their remote urls direct as shown above... Or just use watirgrid if you're looking to parallelize / distribute your tests in a slightly easier fashion =)